# Converting data from a std container to vector<unsigned char> (binary data) and back

Tags: c++, serialization, converters, binary-data

Is there a function (maybe hidden somewhere within Boost libraries) which handles this independently from the type T?

I mean something which has the shape of:

```
template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Container>
void dump(const Container<T> & c, std::vector<unsigned char> & r)
{
    const int d=sizeof(T);
    ...
} 

template <typename T, template <typename, typename...> class Container>
void recover(const std::vector<unsigned char> & r, Container<T> & c)
{
    const int d=sizeof(T);
    ...
}
```

but which has already been written and tested, and avoids me to write down all the different cases and test them and reinvent the wheel worrying about shifts and big and little endian stuff?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is probably Boost.Serialization!